# how to manage the code which does through the following error?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am running the Generative Adversarial Network in my personal system and I am getting the error provided as below, it may be because of GPU accessing problem as explained in this link: ([Function call stack: keras_scratch_graph Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57062456/function-call-stack-keras-scratch-graph-error))

Since I want to run the code in my personal system which does not consist with GPU then how to manage that the code should not access the GPU?

The python code is provided in this link: (https://github.com/eriklindernoren/Keras-GAN/tree/master/pix2pix), where the running code is present in pix2pix.py file.

Produced Error is as follow:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\GaitRecognitionCNN-master13\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py:297: UserWarning: Discrepancy between trainable weights and collected trainable weights, did you set `model.trainable` without calling `model.compile` after ?
  'Discrepancy between trainable weights and collected trainable'
2020-04-08 17:42:33.366720: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/base_collective_executor.cc:217] BaseCollectiveExecutor::StartAbort Failed precondition: Error while reading resource variable _AnonymousVar131 from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Resource localhost/_AnonymousVar131/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
     [[{{node mul_33/ReadVariableOp}}]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/data_rar_and_others/Code_For_GAN5/pix2pix.py", line 217, in <module>
    gan.train(epochs=220, batch_size=4, sample_interval=50)
  File "H:/data_rar_and_others/Code_For_GAN5/pix2pix.py", line 165, in train
    d_loss_real = self.discriminator.train_on_batch([imgs_A, imgs_B], valid)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\GaitRecognitionCNN-master13\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1514, in train_on_batch
    outputs = self.train_function(ins)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\GaitRecognitionCNN-master13\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\backend.py", line 3727, in __call__
    outputs = self._graph_fn(*converted_inputs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\GaitRecognitionCNN-master13\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 1551, in __call__
    return self._call_impl(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\GaitRecognitionCNN-master13\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 1591, in _call_impl
    return self._call_flat(args, self.captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\GaitRecognitionCNN-master13\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 1692, in _call_flat
    ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\GaitRecognitionCNN-master13\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 545, in call
    ctx=ctx)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\GaitRecognitionCNN-master13\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\execute.py", line 67, in quick_execute
    six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError:  Error while reading resource variable _AnonymousVar131 from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Resource localhost/_AnonymousVar131/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
     [[node mul_33/ReadVariableOp (defined at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\GaitRecognitionCNN-master13\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:3009) ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_6898]

Function call stack:
keras_scratch_graph
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error has been resolved when I have changed the

```
from keras.optimizers import Adam
```

with the following

```
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
```